# How to Read pushed data from Firebase Real Time Database under

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Data tree-:

```
data-root
|
---sports
      |
      ----LGhshU00shj(Pushed Key)
                    |
                    ---socks
                           |
                           ---LGhdudy09(Pushed Key):Black
                           |
                           ---LGidiik84(Pushed Key):Red
                           |
                           ---LGiddv74(Pushed Key):Brown
                           |
                           ---colorType:Solid
```

How do I make a toast which shows "Solid:Black","Solid:Red","Solid:Brown"?

**Already Tried-:**

```
 DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Database userWritesRef = rootRef.child("sports").child("socks");
```

And under OnStart() function-:

```
 userWritesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String userWrite = ds.getValue(String.class);
                        Toast.makeText(context, userWrite, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            });
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Please check the updated question @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Thanks for that. I removed my downvote and hope others will follow suit. In general you will find that showing the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will prevent downvotes and close votes, and is the best way to get help here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for that, will surely read the documentation before posting another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code `rootRef.child("sports").child("socks")` will create a reference to `/sports/socks`. Since there is no such node in your database, it will create a listener that reads no data.

What you want is:

```
Database userWritesRef = rootRef.child("sports/LGhshU00shj/socks");
```

Aside from that your data structure is a bit weird, since you're mixing `colorType` (a named property) with what look to be generated colors. You *can* process them in `onDataChange`, it just takes a few extra `if`s:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String colorType = dataSnapshot.child("colorType").getValue(String.class);
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        if (!ds.getKey().equals("colorType")) {
            String userWrite = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Toast.makeText(context, colorType+": "+userWrite, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but the "LGhshU00shj" is a push, not a String that I have kept, that is the problem I am facing

Comment: If you didn't keep the key, how do you expect to load that precise data in the database? In other words: what unique part of the data you're trying to load *do* you know? If you don't know anything about it, all you can do is load *all* data and show that.

Comment: I am trying to prevent any overwrites as the "Red","Brown","Black" is just an example and the user has access to write any string, so I thought push would help me in this case, And Under sports too I wanted each item(in this case socks) to have a unique ID, are there any steps that I can read the data without changing the writing part?

Comment: It's working, I'll work on improving my data structure